# Are there any viable alternatives to wkhtmltopdf on windows, for html to pdf conversion?

Tags: html, windows, open-source, cross-platform, pdf-generation

I've found wkhtmltopdf, which looks good on the surface and works fine in very small cases, but it doesn't provide any real css control over the rendering.

By that I mean it doesn't use the print media type and page breaks are not respected, as well, on windows you can't control the names of some header/footer variables, or generate a TOC off of teh h1 tags.

Are there any real open source alternatives, I've tried xhtml2pdf which is a python library actually called pisa, but it requires reportlab which doesn't play nice windows.

I'm actually programming in .net but if its good and open source, the language isn't a huge issue.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178448/list-of-html-to-pdf-converters but my conclusion was that wkhtmltopdf was miles better than any of the open source alternatives. Page breaks and TOC generation are supported in recent versions.

Comment: At the time this question was written their windows installer was marred with destructive powers of destroying environment variables. It worked well, but there wasn't an api for really adding header and footer stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there was no open source alternative that was simpler, but on windows wkhtmltopdf is just not the best thing, so we paid for a better solution.

Winnovative's PDF library is what we used

Comment: and the choice was?

Comment: i have the same problems you were described in your original post. which solution did you purchased ?

Comment: Winnovative's PDF library is what we used. Adding mvc result types for PDF was very straight forward once we had a library in process as well.

Comment: I found Winnovative's HtmlToPdf no better than wkhtmltopdf. I'm trying to convert pages with google charts or D3.js charts. Winnovative's solution produces PDFs with blank spaces where the charts should be. I used the javascript delay setting.

Comment: @user2444499 in the years since this was first posed, I agree with you, things have converged on similar problems

Answer (score 10):

This is an old stackoverflow question, but because google took me here, it could be helpful for somebody else. 
Weasyprint should support what the author was looking for.
It supports print css features like page break.

Try [weasyprint](http://weasyprint.org/)

Comment: Note weasyprint doesn't render javascript but wkhtmltopdf does!

Comment: Weasyprint is an installation nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

While it is not open-source, I use [ABCPDF](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm). I have a template page in .NET that I use for a wrapper to set up a custom stylesheet for generating PDFs only.

Comment: yeah there are lots of paid alternatives, unfortunately my software will be distributed, so I would need the max license. While my time is valuable, thats a decent chunk of time every year, to tinker more with what kind of works and control it, rather than have not-invented-here syndrome on a core print feature.